# Selecting portion of image from using directx

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am rendering an image using directx 11. The objective is to select pixels from this image and then move it around with mouse. The selection can be of any geometry, like bezier, rectangle etc.

I am new to directx, could someone please suggest a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply render the shape twice. The first instance draw in the color of the background to simulate leaving a hole. The second time use the image as the texture for the shape. You can then move the textured shape around.

Comment: Thanks, can I fill a hole with a image which is larger than that?